# Not predicting all given class opencv

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, opencv

I am using the following code to predict 3 classes but the code is only predicting 1 class. What change is required. Please help.

```
# Loading the cascades
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

def face_extractor(img):
    # Function detects faces and returns the cropped face
    # If no face detected, it returns the input image

    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)

    if faces is ():
        return None

        name="None matching"

        if(pred[0][0]>0.5):
            name='Sam'
        elif(pred[0][1]>0.5):
            name= 'Henry'
        elif(pred[0][2]>0.5):
            name= 'Caje'

        cv2.putText(frame,name, (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2)
    else:
        cv2.putText(frame,"No face found", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello there, Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Please edit your question, so you will get a suitable answer. Read the docs on how to 
[ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're looking to recognize a specific face utilizing OpenCV. If that is the case instead of utilizing a haar cascade which is typically utilized to find objects of the same type (i.e. all people, all faces, etc.) to utilize [cv::FaceRecognizer](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html). You will need to make a training Python script that trains a recognition file then saves it. You would then read the file in your prediction script which should give you the desired result. With some quick googling I was able to dig up [this very detailed article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/) on how to use cv::FaceRecognizer in Python.

Please mark this as the answer if it answered your question.